# Windows 7 boots to an unresponsive black screen with mouse cursor

Tags: windows-7, dell-latitude

Started up the PC one day and it booted to a black screen. I didn't change the configuration in any way, it just happened suddenly.
What it does:
The PC turns on like normal. I get the bios screen. I get the Windows logo screen. Then I get a black screen with a mouse cursor in the middle.
I can move the mouse, but the buttons don't do anything--left or right click.  No keys on the keyboard change the screen. Ctrl+Alt+Del does nothing. Windows key does nothing. Esc does nothing, etc. At this point the only option is to hold down the power button and turn it off.
What I've tried:
I tried to start it in safe mode, but the same thing happens. It shows the system files that are loading. The last file it shows loading is Windows/system32/DRIVERS/AtiPcie.sys then it goes to a black screen with a mouse cursor again; only this time it is in safe mode resolution so the mouse cursor is larger and not as sharp. Also, no keyboard strokes have any affect just as with normal mode.

Comment: If you have a install disk, run startup repair. This sounds like a corruption in the startup files.

Comment: Let it sit at that screen until Windows loads, it is waiting for a critical Windows service to load, be patient.

Comment: I have no disk drive but I have an old backup on an USB. Any sugestions.

Comment: Like patient for how long? I have tried waiting for a while.